# How to send variables (which are declared in the code) in a HTTP POST request body in Go?

Tags: http, go, request

I am using an HTTP client for Golang and the format of the POST request is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/monaco-io/request"
)
var name,pass string.  //assume name and pass hold a value calculated earlier
func main() {
    client := request.Client{
        URL:    "https://google.com",
        Method: "POST",
        Params: map[string]string{"random": "random"},
        **Body:   []byte(`{"username": "ABC", "password": "XYZ"}`)**,
    }
    resp, err := client.Do()

    log.Println(resp.Code, string(resp.Data), err)
}
```

I want to replace "ABC" by my variable *name* and "XYZ" by my variable *pass*.** How can I replace a constant string value by a variable which holds some string value calculated in a function within my code.

Comment: You're asking how to marshal JSON. There are countless examples on SO, and on the Internet. If the dupe question isn't sufficient, do a search for more examples.

Answer (score -2):

simply use `fmt.Sprintf` function

```golang
fmt.Sprintf(`{"username": "%s", "password": "%s"}`, name, pass)
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf

full code will look like

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"


    "github.com/monaco-io/request"  // must be v0.0.2
)

var name, pass string //assume name and pass hold a value calculated earlier

func main() {
    client := request.Client{
        URL:    "https://google.com",
        Method: "POST",
        Params: map[string]string{"random": "random"},
        Body:   []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"username": "%s", "password": "%s"}`, name, pass)),
    }
    resp, err := client.Do()

    log.Println(resp.Code, string(resp.Data), err)
}
```

Comment: I tried the above function but I could not get it to work when I put it inside the byte array in the request body. Can you clarify the body format? I tried 2 different formats:
`Body : []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"username": "%s", "password": "%s"}`, name, pass)) ` AND 
`Body : []byte(`fmt.Sprintf(`{"username": "%s", "password": "%s"}`, name, pass)`) ` but both of the above formats gave syntax error

Comment: What is your error response?  Maybe we can check the version of package "monaco-io/request" in the go.mod file first. The package "monaco-io/request" has a lot of change in v1, and your use case can only be used in v0.0.2.

Comment: It says unexpected {, expecting expression when I use
Body:   []byte({fmt.Sprintf(`{"username":"&s"}`,name)}),

Comment: the format verbs is "%s" instead of "&s". there are more info https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing

Comment: I am sorry I used %s only, printed &s by mistake.

Comment: try to change `[]byte({ string })` => `[]byte( string )`

Comment: Never use `fmt.Sprintf` to create JSON. Do actual JSON marshaling instead!

Comment: Future readers: please don't do this.